# Display a single image in Apostrophe CMS / Nunjucks

Tags: node.js, apostrophe, nunjucks, apostrophe-cms

Very simple question coming up!

- In my Apostrophe header I want to 'hard-code' an image to always
  display in a certain (banner) location.
- I do NOT want any editor/user to be able to change or remove the image
- so I'm assuming I do NOT need to use any singleton-type approach
- and that I do NOT need any type of widget.

So, all I'm trying to do is the most basic of HTML:

```
<img src="myfile.jpg">
```

Yet I face 2 problems:

1) when I use the above I get

> "TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null"

...followed by lots of errors, then

> "^^^^^ LOOK UP HERE FOR THE LOCATION WITHIN YOUR HELPER e.stack: 
>   Template render error: (apostrophe-pages:notFound.html) Template
>   render error: (apostrophe-pages:notFound.html)"

...followed by lots more errors

2) I've no idea which directory in which to store the image (should it be in a module directory?). I don't want to store it in the main 'image library'

Presumably some form of Nunjucks coding is required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't get that error from having a broken src in regular old HTML. Maybe paste the full error or comment out some recently added code out to deduce that error.

To answer your question, Apostrophe makes the `/public` directory available as the root, so if you place an image file in, say, `/public/images/myfile.jpg` you should be able to access it from `<img src="/images/myfile.jpg" />` in your template.

Comment: Yep, this is the key information — if you use a relative path (with no /) then Apostrophe will try to find that file where it isn't.

Comment: Thanks - I'd wrongly assumed the 50 lines (really) of error messages I'd seen were symptomatic of a more complex nunjucks/apostrophe error, rather than a simple "put-the-image-in-the-correct-directory-and-link-to-it-properly-type-of-error".

So now all solved - thanks!

Comment: That error message was probably about something entirely unrelated, like some bad Nunjucks syntax elsewhere in the file, or your HTML being inside Nunjucks {{ }} markup rather than just standing happily on its own.